# how to use "mysqld -O thread_stack=#"

Tags: mysql, java

I keep getting this error whether I run my query from the terminal or from within Java. Anyone has some instructions how to resolve this?

```
Thread stack overrun:  5768 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.
Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

BTW: I am using mac osx lion

Comment: what is the query you are trying to run?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Rolando thought about what this variable does before answering. Don't set the thread_stack to 32M. It's is allocated per connection and 100 connections is going use 3.2GB.

```
thread_stack = 192K
```

Setting it to the fairly standard 192k should be fine.